# Button does not get clicked when pressed, in presense of SeekArc view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I am building an app in which the layout consists of one button, below which there is an seekarc view
( used code from github project at  https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc ).

The app runs successfully on the test phone, but when I try to click the button, it doesn't click it, but just adjusts the progess on the seekarc, *even when I do not touch the seekarc at all*. It is as though the seekarc has taken the complete focus, leaving the button defocussed.

How do I modify my xml such that when I click on the button, the button click should occur successfully?

My xml is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch On"
    android:id = "@+id/onbtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:touchInside="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to put your SeekArc into a framelayout

Comment: within the same layout file right?

Comment: yes within the same layout.

Comment: Did you face any exceptions or any force close errors?

Comment: Nope.. issue got resolved with @Harikrishnan's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your `SeekArc` is covering the button. You are using a `RelativeLayout`, so you need to mention that the `SeekArc` has to come below your button. Change the seekarc code as following:

```
<com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/onbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:touchInside="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a **RelativeLayout**, so if you want to place **SeekArc** below the **Button**, add the *android:layout_below="@id/onbtn"* attribute to the **SeekArc**.